# Combining Reference Names in a Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to write something I thought was a simple piece of code.

I have multiple charts where the layout has to update based on user input (the data for the series are defined in another sub). I have defined a number of series with specific RGB colours assigned - these are called "Ser1", "Ser2", "Ser3" etc. The sub is supposed to loop through each chart and update the colours assigned to these series.
Dimension "i" is the number of series to be updated. To make it simple I just want to combine the number of series "i" with the series name (i.e. "Ser" + "i" = "Ser1"). I have written an exmaple of what I am trying to do below. Currently the code does not reference the series correctly (i.e. it does not combine "Ser" with "i" to make out "Ser1", "Ser2" etc.), I have have been searching for a solution, but I have not been able to figure out a way to combine "Ser" and "i" correctly anywhere.

```
Sub ChartLayout_2()
With Sheets("Table")

Dim Ser1, Ser2, Ser3 As Long

Ser1 = RGB(0, 112, 192)
Ser2 = RGB(222, 28, 133)
Ser3 = RGB(136, 0, 56)

Set Cht = .ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart
With Cht
For i = 1 To j
.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Ser & i
Next i
End With

Set Cht = .ChartObjects("Chart 10").Chart
With Cht
For i = 1 To j
.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = Ser & i
Next i
End With

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't construct variable names like that, you need an array instead.

Where do you define `j`?

```
Sub ChartLayout_2()

Dim Ser(1 To 3) As Long

With Sheets("Table")
    Ser(1) = RGB(0, 112, 192)
    Ser(2) = RGB(222, 28, 133)
    Ser(3) = RGB(136, 0, 56)

    Set Cht = .ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart
    With Cht
        For i = 1 To j 'j must equal 3
            .SeriesCollection(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Ser(i)
        Next i
    End With

    Set Cht = .ChartObjects("Chart 10").Chart
    With Cht
        For i = 1 To j
            .SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = Ser(i)
        Next i
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

---

Or

```
Sub ChartLayout_2()

Dim Ser(1 To 3) As Long

With Sheets("Table")
    Ser(1) = RGB(0, 112, 192)
    Ser(2) = RGB(222, 28, 133)
    Ser(3) = RGB(136, 0, 56)

    For i = 1 To j 'j must equal 3
        .ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Ser(i)
        .ChartObjects("Chart 10").Chart.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = Ser(i)
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you SJR, that made it work. This was simply due to my lack of understanding about how to construct variables.

"j" was defined in a previous sub that identifies the number of series to populate the chart with (= "j") as well as the source data.